Request execution error, Could not extract response
Trying to deploy CloudGateway to AWS Fargate but receiving the below error.
Frequent error logs for eureka.
Please find the below error logs.
I can see the service is getting registered to eureka but still the below error exists along with cache refresh related errors.
Using spring boot 3.1.2 , JDK 17, Spring cloud 2022.0.2.
Please help.
1734523859501,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.500+05:30  WARN [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath."
1734523859616,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.615+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING"
1734523859630,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.630+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1"
1734523859634,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.634+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.636+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.637+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.637+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.637+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.637+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.637+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true"
1734523859637,"2024-12-18T17:40:59.637+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server"
1734523860070,"2024-12-18T17:41:00.070+05:30  INFO [apigateway-service,,] 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://abcd:8761/eureka/}, exception=Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [text/html] stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [text/html]"
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1132)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1115)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:865)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1045)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:958)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:396)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:247)
1734523860070,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:242)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:68)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:320)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
1734523860070,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:128)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:116)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
1734523860070,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getEurekaClient(<generated>)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357)
1734523860070,  at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
1734523860070,  at com.example.ApigatewayApplication.main(ApigatewayApplication.java:25)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
1734523860070,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
1734523860070,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
1734523860070,  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)

